# Rails - Warning : Insecure world writable dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have this warning when I run `rails s`

```
/home/dixon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:301: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/dixon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@ukm/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/home/dixon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:301: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/dixon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@ukm/bin in PATH, mode 040777
```

I try with this

```
sudo chmod go-w /home/dixon
```

But didn't change, warning still appear.

Comment: `sudo chmod -R go-w /home/dixon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@ukm/`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra : oh I forgot with `-R` option..

Comment: is that working now?

Comment: @PardeepDhingra : yes, I'm use `sudo chmod -R go-w /home/dixon`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo chmod go-w /home/dixon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@ukm/bin
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-R` for recursively giving permissions.

```
sudo chmod -R go-w /home/dixon
```